# Heroku error in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tried many things given in diff blogs. Still not working. Can someone help me with the following error??

```
**sudo heroku keys:add**

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>': no such file to load -- net/https. Try running apt-get install libopenssl-ruby (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.3/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.3/lib/heroku.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.3/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a debian package it seems.

Did you try running the command in the error message? ie

apt-get install libopenssl-ruby

Comment: yes Michael, i tried that. No use. Still getting the same error. Any clue?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libruby' instead of 'libopenssl-ruby'
libruby is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 309 not upgraded.

Comment: @jithesh: don't you need the public key at the end of your keys:add command? ie

`sudo heroku keys:add C:\path\to\my\id_rsa.pub`

Also you might need to clear your keys first, `heroku keys:clear`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem for some time.  Here's how I solved it on my Debian machine:

1. sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline5-dev curl git zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev
2. rvm install ruby 1.9.2 [or whatever version you are using]

The likely problem is you're missing some dependencies, and the error messages are pretty vague as to which these are.

The fine print on the dependencies is actually available through 'rvm notes', but the above seemed to solve this problem for me.